# Why does not http call /usr/bin/http instead of /usr/local/bin/http?

Tags: linux, http, python3

Show my path:

```
echo  $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/go/bin
```

Issue http command:

```
http  --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/http: No such file or directory
```

Where does http locate?

```
which http
/usr/bin/http
```

Issue http command with absolute path:

```
/usr/bin/http  --version
0.9.8
```

Why does not `http` call `/usr/bin/http` instead of `/usr/local/bin/http` ?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that when your shell started `/usr/local/bin/http` was still present. Then something happened, the file got deleted but shell doesn't know about it.

What you need to do is to let shell forget remembered program locations by executing:

```
hash -r
```

to view full help of the `hash` command, you can do `help hash`